# symbolic toolbox

Tags: matlab

is it possible to add (install) symbolic toolbox from earlier versions of MATLAB to newer one?
if it is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot use an old toolbox in a newer MATLAB release. You need a current license for that toolbox. And if you have a current license for this toolbox, then use the current version.

Is the issue that you prefer some behavior of the older version?